# Unable to Recode Multiple Columns in an R Data frame

Tags: recode

So, I've got a dataframe that looks like the [given image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Kgfj.jpg). I've been trying to recode the "Yes" and "No" values to 0 and 1 in the columns starting with "C_0". These columns correspond to the positions 8 through 22 in my dataframe.

First, I tried a simple recode using base R. My code was as follows:
zero_to_six <- recode(zero_to_six[,8:22], "Yes" = 1, "No" = 0, "NA" = NA)

I got the following error message: The error message I got was: Error in UseMethod("recode") : no applicable method for 'recode' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"

Then, I thought I'd try recoding the data using dplyr. My code was as follows:

zero_to_six <- zero_to_six %>%

mutate_at(vars(starts_with("C_0")), recode("Yes" = 1, "No" = 0, "NA" = NA))

The error message I got was: Error in recode.numeric(Yes = 1, No = 0, `NA` = NA) : argument ".x" is missing, with no default

Can someone help me figure out where I am going wrong, please? I'd greatly appreciate the favor!